# saving a SVG marker to a layer for sharing

Tags: qgis, point, svg

I have a layer which consists of point data. I have switched the symbology of the layer to a svg image that I loaded in. To maintain the symbology I went to LayerProperties>style and then i saved the style. However, when I open the layer on a different computer (one with out the svg saved in) and apply the layer style nothing come up. How can I save a picture marker to a layer file and still be able to send it via email etc. and have it show up on another computer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good solution for sharing symbols with SVGs yet. Here's a [recent discussion on the mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/SVG-paths-in-print-layout-templates-td5271340.html) and the [resulting feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15019).

For now, you have to manually make sure to copy the SVG and configure QGIS to find it on the other PC.